# Finding limit of $\frac{2}{2^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm trying to find the limit of $\frac{2}{2^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}$ by finding 2 limits smaller and greater than the denominator and thus find the limit of the denominator and thus find the limit of the entire thing. can't find the 2 sequences needed for that. I need to use squeeze theorem to find the limit of the denominator.

Comment: Instead, maybe consider $$\frac{2}{2^{1/2^n}}=2^{1-2^{-n}}.$$

Comment: @AndrewChin I was told to use it like that by the instructor

Comment: What's the premise? Seems needlessly complicated.

Comment: @AndrewChin I don't know, those were the instructions.

Comment: As in, what was the overarching lesson or lecture about?

Comment: @AndrewChin just more practice in finding limits and in this particular exercise using the "sandwich rule" I don't know if that's the correct name of it in English.

Comment: @DarkLeader It has [many names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: @J.G. Yeah thanks. can you help me find two sequences to find the limit of the denominator that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit confused as to why your professor insists on using squeeze theorem, but I guess one way this could work for the denominator is $$2^{\frac{1}{n!}}\leq 2^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}\leq2^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
Which, if you want to see in action check out this Desmos link: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ngfb9ds7dc

Anyways, if we take limits of all of these we get $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{n!}}\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}2^{\frac{1}{n}}$$
And then 
$$1\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}\leq1$$
so $$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{2^{n}}} = 1$$ By squeeze theorem

Comment: You can bound below by $1$, which makes squeeze theorem slightly more natural.

Comment: I also was evaluating such kind of derivation and adding that but at the end we are using that by continuity with $a_n \to 0 \implies 2^{a_n}\to 1$ nd therefore squeeze theorem is adding nothing to the solution.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but can you think of another way to use squeeze theorem to get a similar result?

Answer (score 2):

We have that by continuity

$$\frac{1}{2^n} \to 0 \implies\frac{2}{2^{\frac{1}{2^n}}} \to \frac{2}{2^{0}}=2$$

As an alternative by squeeze theorem we have that

$$0\le\frac{1}{2^n}\le \frac1n$$

and therefore

$$\frac{2}{2^{0}}\le \frac{2}{2^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}\le \frac{2}{2^{\frac{1}{n}}}$$

and we can conclude that the limit is one sinceboth RHS and LHS tends to $2$ but in this case we are using the same result by continuity therefore it seems a not effective method in this case.

Comment: I can't just say that 1/(2^n) goes to 0. I need to find 2 other sequences, one larger and one smaller and show that both have the same limit and thus 1/(2^n) has the same limit as well

Comment: @DarkLeader Ah ok, sorry I didn' get this point. I try to add such kind of solution. You need to use squeeze theorem then.

Comment: well I was just told by some friends that they used the same method you used, thank you! guess I'll use it as well.

Comment: @DarkLeader That's the simpler of course and math need to be as lazy as possible with the effort to reach a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

As $n$ becomes large $\frac{1}{2^n}$ becomes very small and positive. So $2^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$ becomes very close to $1$ as $n$ becomes large. So overall $\frac{2}{2^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}$ approaches $\frac{2}{1} = 2$ as $n$ becomes large.

Comment: I can't just say as  n becomes large that $\frac{1}{2^n}$ becomes very close to 1. I need to find 2 other limits that are greater and smaller than it and show that both of both have the same limit and thus $\frac{1}{2^n}$ has the same limit as well.